# Removing Block of XML With Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Let's say that I have a table called **Config** which contains one XML column with XML data stored in it.

SELECT * FROM Config

Returns:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>402297</Key>
    <Value>1f98e48c0302ae2c1dfc3c2a781df2fb</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403121</Key>
    <Value>6784bf087329f2bef51c0b61753d22c3</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403131</Key>
    <Value>3711133c97ccca28c3a89ef1bd424fdf</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
```

I want to write a stored proc called **DeleteXMLByKey** that takes an integer and will remove the block of XML where the key is.

So, if I write:

EXEC DeleteXMLByKey 402297

I am expecting that when I do a Select * from the table, that I get:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403121</Key>
    <Value>6784bf087329f2bef51c0b61753d22c3</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403131</Key>
    <Value>3711133c97ccca28c3a89ef1bd424fdf</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
```

(This XML doesn't have the 402297 block anymore)

Is there any way that I can do this through SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT  
       Tbl.Col.value('Key[1]', 'int') [Key],  
       Tbl.Col.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(100)') [Value]
FROM   @xml.nodes('//ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring[1]/KeyValueOfstringstring') Tbl(Col)
where Tbl.Col.value('Key[1]', 'int') <> 402297
for xml path ('KeyValueOfstringstring'), Root('ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring')
```

I had to change your XML though to get it to work.  The ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring tag is not terminated.

EDIT:
In your specific case, you needed to update all the xml columns in a table, so your code might look something like this:

```
--declare variable with xml
declare @xml as xml
set @xml =
'<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring> xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>402297</Key>
    <Value>1f98e48c0302ae2c1dfc3c2a781df2fb</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403121</Key>
    <Value>6784bf087329f2bef51c0b61753d22c3</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403131</Key>
    <Value>3711133c97ccca28c3a89ef1bd424fdf</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
'

--create temp table with xml field
select @xml xmlfield
into #xml

--update the xml field to remove key 4002297
update #xml
set xmlfield =convert
    (xml,
    (SELECT  
           Tbl.Col.value('Key[1]', 'int') [Key],  
           Tbl.Col.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(100)') [Value]
    FROM   xmlfield.nodes('//ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring[1]/KeyValueOfstringstring') Tbl(Col)
    where Tbl.Col.value('Key[1]', 'int') <> 402297
    for xml path ('KeyValueOfstringstring'), Root('ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring'), Type
    ))
from #xml

--View Results
select * from #xml
```

Results:

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403121</Key>
    <Value>6784bf087329f2bef51c0b61753d22c3</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
  <KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <Key>403131</Key>
    <Value>3711133c97ccca28c3a89ef1bd424fdf</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringstring>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>
```

Comment: I added more context so you can see exactly what I'm running on my server.  Make sure your XML tags match exactly.  XML is case sensitive.  If it can't find the Key tag in the spot it's expecting, it won't return the row either.